# Proper way to Parse a Payload in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following payload:

```
[{:payload=>
   "{\"user\":\"test\",\"job\":\"Test\",\"username\":\"Bob\",\"blocks\":[{\"type\":\"section\",\"text\":{\"type\":\"mrkdwn\",\"text\":\"this is the title\"}},{\"type\":\"context\",\"elements\":[{\"type\":\"mrkdwn\",\"text\":\"Test\"}]},{\"type\":\"divider\"}]}"}]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to extract it. I tried

```
JSON.parse(response)
```

But I get the following error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

How can I extract this value to something where I can do something like:

```
response.job == "test" ?
```

Comment: Your question isn't asked well. We'd like to see the minimal, runnable, code that demonstrates what you tried. As is it looks like you didn't really try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you meant to say:

```
response = [{:payload => "{\"user\":\"test\",\"job\":\"Test\",\"username\":\"Bob\",\"blocks\":[{\"type\":\"section\",\"text\":{\"type\":\"mrkdwn\",\"text\":\"this is the title\"}},{\"type\":\"context\",\"elements\":[{\"type\":\"mrkdwn\",\"text\":\"Test\"}]},{\"type\":\"divider\"}]}"}]
```

Then `response` is an [array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html) with one element. That one element is a [hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html). You would thus access the `payload` with:

```
payload = JSON.parse(response.first[:payload])
=> {
        "user" => "test",
         "job" => "Test",
    "username" => "Bob",
      "blocks" => [
        [0] {
            "type" => "section",
            "text" => {
                "type" => "mrkdwn",
                "text" => "this is the title"
            }
        },
        [1] {
                "type" => "context",
            "elements" => [
                [0] {
                    "type" => "mrkdwn",
                    "text" => "Test"
                }
            ]
        },
        [2] {
            "type" => "divider"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `payload` object is then a hash and its child elements can be accessed using the standard `[]` call:

```
job = payload['job']
=> "Test"
```